# JQuery - Pass value of variable to index value of class

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm new to js and have only been learning for about a week so be kind. The script below alters the src of an iframe to match the custom data-attribute of the same iframe when a link with a class of .thumb is clicked.

This works fine but its currently changing the iframe src of all classes of all iframes with a parent div class of .gallery. I just want to change the iframe src of the .gallery with the same index value as the variable 'clicked'.

```
//When an link with a class of .thumb is clicked

$(document).on('click', '.thumb', function () {

    //variable index is the index of the links parent 'li'
    var clicked = $(this).parent('li').index();

    // Find iFrames of all .comm-gallery elements and alter their src to iframes data-src    value
    $('.gallery').find("iframe").prop("src", function(){

        // Set their src attribute to the value of data-src
        return $(this).data("src");
    });
});
```

I've tried numerous loop solutions over the past few hours but none have worked and, as I know little about js at this point, I imagine that I am the lowest common denominator in this. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Do you try `.eq` like `$('.gallery').find("iframe").eq(clicked).prop(..`?

Comment: Already accepted the other answer, but this also worked. Thanks buddy!

Comment: If `.eq` works for you, then I suggest you go by that. It is more like iterating 1 item vs iteration all item and comparing the index.

Comment: Will do! trying to make it as lightweight as possible so this is perfect!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add condition before returning data-src

```
$('.gallery').find("iframe").prop("src", function(){
if($(this).index() == clicked)
  // Set their src attribute to the value of data-src
   return $(this).data("src");
});
```

Comment: `.eq` seems to be a lot better than doing a comparison inside. That is if I am understanding it correctly.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! This worked perfectly and makes more logical sense than the .each method I was trying to achieve! Thank you thank you thank you! I'd +1 you but it won't allow me because i'm a noob with a low rep so I hope a "You're awesome" will do!

Answer (score 0):

The jquery eq selector is what your after:

http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/

so this:

```
$('.gallery').find("iframe").prop("src", function(){

    // Set their src attribute to the value of data-src
    return $(this).data("src");
});
```

becomes:

```
$('.gallery').find("iframe").eq(clicked).prop("src", function(){

    // Set their src attribute to the value of data-src
    return $(this).data("src");
});
```

Comment: Thanks! Going to take a few hours to sit down and learn about this as its obviously a fundamental part of js. My js learning in the last week has been staggered between the basics and the niche areas which is not the best approach.

Answer (score 0):

you to have select the element that has 'gallery' css class with index of clicked li.

```
$(document).on('click', '.thumb', function () {
var clicked = $(this).parent('li').index();
$('.gallery').eq(clicked).find("iframe").prop("src",function({
return$(this).data("src");
});
});
```